# node.js Cannot GET /socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have the following app with express/socket.io (the app is listening and live without any errors).
When I http-request it I get the following error:

```
GET http://xxxxxxx.com:3035/socket.io/1/?t=1449090610579 400 (Bad Request)
```

And on the socket.io reponse at http://xxxxxxx.com:3035/socket.io I get:

```
Cannot GET /socket.io
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    sio= require('socket.io'),
    fs=require('fs'),
    app = express();

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'xxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxxx',
        database: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    }
);
connection.connect();

// Start the server
var server=app.listen(3035, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d",3035);
});
app.io=io=sio.listen(server);
.
.
.
```

on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://xxxxxx.com:3035');
```

Comment: Looks like it can't get the static script file because you're missing a basic static route.

Comment: This was running well before I migrate to a new server. not sure what is missing exactly!

Comment: Then it's probably not the static route thing, Socket.io creates it's own routes if I remember correctly. Something changed when migrating, and the URL is no longer correct, you probably have to do some fault searching on your own.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to figure out. thank you for the hint.

Comment: var express = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var sio = require('socket.io')(http);

Answer (score 1):

Your sio is a function. You need to call it with your server as an argument.

Add 
`server=require('http').Server(app)
sio=require('socket.io')(server)`

Comment: I have tried the same in vain. Thank you. I will try around with this!

Answer (score 1):

`io.connect()` takes a URL such as `http://example.com:3035`.

You are passing `xxxxxx.com:3035` which is not a proper URL form.

---

Also, note that if you're just trying to connect to the same server and port as the web page came from, you can just use:

```
io()
```

or

```
io.connect()
```

And the socket.io library will connect back to the same host and port as the web page.

Comment: I was using the full URL with http. Sorry I did a typing mistake while masking the domain, I will correct it. using io() broke my app not sure why!

Comment: Thank you by the way for your answer. more hints allows me to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize default connection on client side by

```
io.connect( "/" );
```

According to documentation by default socket.io will connect to the same host and port where rendered webpage is. The `/` in the path states to connect to default namespace.